# displaying data in a table flask sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am trying to display some data out of a table onto a html page, I am using sql alchemy to query my database. at the moment, the table appears but with no data in it, even though the sqlalchemy table does have data inside of it, I am unsure if this is to do with my query or how I am attempting to display it in html, any help solving this would be appreciated!

python:

```py
@app.route("/home")
@login_required
def home():
    _id = session["user_id"]

    return render_template(
        "home.html",
        users=users,
        values=users.query.filter_by(id=_id).first(),
        items=bills.query.filter_by(user_id=_id),
    )
```

sqlalchemy table:

```py
class bills(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'bills'

    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column("user_id", db.Integer())
    name = db.Column("name", db.String(100))
    price = db.Column("price", db.Float())

    def __init__(self, user_id, name, price):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

html page:

```html
<div class="card">
    <h3>Yearly Income £{{ values.income}}</h3>
    <table class="tabel tabel-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Bill Name</th>
                <th>Price of Bill</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in items %}
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">{{ items.name }}</td>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold">£{{ items.price }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```